# understanding how timthumb works

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, performance, wordpress

Coming from Rails background, I used to work with paperclip plugin, which was creating from images attachments thumbs with predefined sizes.

In wordpress, I am little confused. Here is my question or points that need more clarification:

1. Does timthumb creates thumbs and saves it to disk upon uploading images for the first time? or It just resizes images on the fly and caches them?
2. If it resizes on the fly, why I see different sizes of each image in `uploads` directory, such as `filename.jpg` `filename-150x150.jpg` and so on?
3. Isn't better for performance to just create the thumbs once upon uploading and serving them directly without calling a script? and if so, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typically it resizes and caches the images upon their first request.
2. You're probably seeing the image resizing that WP does. These are controlled in the settings
3. Debatable. Yes in that it could all be done at your command, no in that someone could upload 1000 images and resizing them all at once could cause problems with the site. Thus spreading out the resizing could result in balancing the load demands. Also, parameters can be passed via the script when a page loads that creates a custom thumbnail. So if you decide your thumbnails were 10px too narrow, you can run it again and it will resize from the original. Plus the filename of the base image remains untouched - if your code says image.jpg, it will always be image.jpg, not matter the size. So if you've got 10,000 instances of thumbnails, and they all reference image-150x150 and now you want them to be 160x160, you either have to change the image names being referenced, or have a nonsensical filename. TimThumb provides a pretty good workaround for that.

Here's some basic timthumb/wordpess performance tips http://www.dollarshower.com/timthumb-and-wordpress-blog-performance/

Comment: Very helpful, especially the third answer. Thanks